# Removing array index reference when using json_encode()

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have made a small application using jQuery's `datepicker`. I am setting unavailable dates to it from a JSON file which looks like this:

```
{ "dates": ["2013-12-11", "2013-12-10", "2013-12-07", "2013-12-04"] }
```

I would like to check if a date given is already in this list and remove it if so. My current code looks like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['date'])) //the date given
{
    if ($_GET['roomType'] == 2)
    {
        $myFile = "bookedDates2.json";
        $date = $_GET['date'];
        if (file_exists($myFile))
        {
            $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($myFile), true);
            if (!in_array($date, $arr['dates']))
            {
                $arr['dates'][] = $_GET['date']; //adds the date into the file if it is not there already
            }
            else
            {
                foreach ($arr['dates'] as $key => $value)
                {
                    if (in_array($date, $arr['dates']))
                    {
                        unset($arr['dates'][$key]);
                        array_values($arr['dates']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $arr = json_encode($arr);
        file_put_contents($myFile, $arr);
    }
}
```

My problem here is that after I encode the array again, it looks like this:

```
{ "dates": ["1":"2013-12-11", "2":"2013-12-10", "3":"2013-12-07", "4":"2013-12-04"] }
```

Is there a way to find the date match in the JSON file and remove it, without the keys appearing after the encode?

Comment: it does not look like that, but like this: `{ "dates": {"1":"2013-12-11", "2":"2013-12-10", "3":"2013-12-07", "4":"2013-12-04"} }`. Diff: the curly bracket wrap an object

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/array_values) for your issue:

```
$arr['dates'] = array_values($arr['dates']);
//..
$arr = json_encode($arr);
```

Why? Because you're unsetting array's key without re-ordering it. So after this the only way to keep that in JSON will be encode keys too. After applying `array_values()`, however, you'll get ordered keys (starting from `0`) which can be encoded properly without including keys.

Comment: @DanieleCruciani [it does](https://3v4l.org/3DDEZ#v720)

Comment: yes, sorry. My misunderstood was about json definition, and how much php is pedant about it. Node Js accept to parse an array as a json object, in fact `a=[];JSON.stringify(a);` output "[]", because `typeof a` output "object". In PHP this is not possible, because by its own definition type of array is not an object (like it is in javascript), but php pretends to know js better than a js engine.

Answer (score 4):

You are ignoring the return value of `array_values` in your existing attempt to reindex the array. Correct is

```
$arr['dates'] = array_values($arr['dates']);
```

The reindexing should also be moved outside the `foreach` loop, there is no point in reindexing multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

In [Laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections)(just in case) you can do

```
    $newArray = $collection->values()->toArray();
```

or

```
    $jsonEncoded = $collection->values()->toJson();
```

Comment: This is such a clean answer for collections. `$collection->values()->toJson( JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );` Is perfect for saving json prettified to files.

Comment: @Second2None You are right. thanks :) you may want to suggest it as an edit

Answer (score 1):

Just pass second parameter as '`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`' to `json_encode()` function:

```
json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

or

```
json_encode($arr, 128);
```