# PHP convert array into JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [string] => something
            [name] => test
            [int] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [string] => another
            [name] => test2
            [int] => 43
        )
)
```

Which i want to convert to a specific JSON layout looking like this

```
[
    {
        "string": "something",
        "name": "test",
        "int": "1"
    },
    {
        "string": "another",
        "name": "test2",
        "int": "43"
    }
]
```

The problem is that, when i use the built in PHP function `json_encode` my output does not look the way i want but instead look like this

```
{"0":{"string":"something","name":"test","int":1},"1":{"string":"another","name":"test2","int":43}}
```

Basicly is there a way to remove the indexes from the conversion ?

Comment: Probably you have unset some items or your index keys are strings (even if they looks as numeric). Short solution: use `json_encode( array_values( $yourArray ) )`. Better solution: show the code in which you create the array.

Comment: use array_values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372982/removing-array-index-reference-when-using-json-encode-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Please try this snippet code :

```
$data = [];
$data[0] = array(
    "string" => "something",
    "name" => "test",
    "int" => 1
);
$data[1] = array(
    "string" => "another",
    "name" => "test2",
    "int" => 43
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Output :

```
[{"string":"something","name":"test","int":1},{"string":"another","name":"test2","int":43}]
```