# json_encode returns column name and array index

Tags: php, json

I'm having a small issue with my code. What I want to do is show the results of a select as json. This is how I do it:

```
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $test = json_encode($row);
}
```

But it returns that:

```
{0: "34.8", 1: "1441098255", 2: "1", col1: "34.8", col2: "1441098255", col3: "1"}
```

And I want it like this:

```
{0: "34.8", 1: "1441098255", 2: "1"}
```

Or this:

```
{col1: "34.8", col2: "1441098255", col3: "1"}
```

I tried doing [what they say here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372982/removing-array-index-reference-when-using-json-encode-in-php), but to no avail.

***Edit***: The replies are helpful, and they do what I want. The problem now is that I have some sneaky part that for some reason can't seem to get rid of. Here's the resulting json string:

```
{"col1":"34.8","0":"34.8","col2":"1441098255","col3":"1"}
```

That "0":"34.8" seems to not want to leave, and I have absolutely no idea where it comes from, and if I change the column order, it always duplicates whatever column comes first. If I put "col3" as the first one, it displays this:

```
{"col3":"1","0":"1","col2":"1441098255","col1":"34.8"}
```

***Edit2:*** Turns out the solution was much simpler than what I tried. Here's how to display it properly:

```
while ($arr = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: you can easily build the right format in your loop for the desired output then after the loop output the array in json

Comment: @Gert Do you mind explaining how to do that?

Comment: It looks like you've got a database result indexed both by numeric IDs and column names - you should be able to specify which you want when fetching the result (in the call to `PDOStatement::fetch` or similar). You haven't included your database code though, so it's impossible to say exactly what you'd need to change.

Comment: @iainn you mean the select? I use `$query = $this->dbh->prepare(select stuff...)` followed by `$query->execute();`

Comment: what is the json data being used for  example mobile app to connect to DB ? @Newwt

Comment: @Gert It's being used to send it back to an html page and do a fancy graph.

Comment: @iainn Due to a silly typo I made, your solution didn't work. I now typed it well and it does work now! If you want to post your solution as an answer so I can put it as solved, that's be bananas, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` flag

```
$keys = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $filtered = array_filter((Array) $row, function($key) use($keys) {
        return in_array($key, $keys);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    $test = json_encode($filtered);
}
```

Notice: If your `$row` is array not object you don't need to cast it to array  `(Array) $row`

Comment: I get `Call to undefined function array_fiter()`

Comment: @Newwt its literal mistake should be filter

Comment: mother of god, and I didn't even notice it haha! It does exactly what I wanted it to do, thank you!

Comment: I just noticed it still adds something: `{"col1":"34.8","0":"34.8","col2":"1441098255","col2":"1"}` I don't know where that "`"0":"34.8"`"comes from.

Comment: @Newwt i guess from different place because `$query = [["col1"=>"x",1=>"y"]];` returns filtered

Comment: I have absolutely no idea where it comes from. I've changed and rewritten all my code three times already and that sneaky 0 keeps coming back.

Comment: to be honest you should follow @iainn idea, how comes you get both numeric and associative keys in array?

Comment: FIXED IT! I followed iainn's idea, but didn't work because it had a typo (on my side), so I tried other methods. Well-written, the code is shorter and works perfectly. I'll now edit my question with the solution. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_chunk to get the first three element of $row.

```
json_encode(array_chunk($row, 3, true)[0]);
```

Comment: why not `array_slice($row, 0, 3)`

Comment: This returns something weird with the json: `{"col1":"34.8","0":"34.8","col2":"1441098255"}`. Edit: I just noticed it does the same with the answer I marked as "solved". hm.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $data=array();
foreach ($query as $row) {

   $data[]=$row;
   //$test = json_encode($row);
}

$test = json_encode( $data);
```

Comment: Consider providing an explanation for you answer