# delete an element of given key of array in php

Tags: php

```
    $nesAry=array();
$nesAry["name"]="abc";
$nesAry["email"]="abc@email.com";

$nesAry1=array();
$nesAry1["name"]="abc1";
$nesAry1["email"]="abc1@email.com";

$nesAry2=array();
$nesAry2["name"]="abc2";
$nesAry2["email"]="abc2@email.com";


$responseAry = array();
$responseAry[0]=$nesAry;
$responseAry[1]=$nesAry1;
$responseAry[2]=$nesAry2;


echo json_encode($responseAry); // here  output like this => [{"name":"abc","email":"abc@email.com"},{"name":"abc1","email":"abc1@email.com"},{"name":"abc2","email":"abc2@email.com"}]

unset($responseAry[1]);

echo "------------removed 1--------";


echo json_encode($responseAry); // but here output like this => {"0":{"name":"abc","email":"abc@email.com"},"2":{"name":"abc2","email":"abc2@email.com"}}
```

**I want Out put Like this after removing an element  \n [{"name":"abc","email":"abc@email.com"},{"name":"abc2","email":"abc2@email.com"}]**

**Please Help me**

Comment: [Removing array index reference when using json_encode in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20372982/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

Try to regenerate your array after unset an item:

```
$nesAry=array();
$nesAry["name"]="abc";
$nesAry["email"]="abc@email.com";

$nesAry1=array();
$nesAry1["name"]="abc1";
$nesAry1["email"]="abc1@email.com";

$nesAry2=array();
$nesAry2["name"]="abc2";
$nesAry2["email"]="abc2@email.com";


$responseAry = array();
$responseAry[0]=$nesAry;
$responseAry[1]=$nesAry1;
$responseAry[2]=$nesAry2;


echo json_encode($responseAry); // __here  output like this => [{"name":"abc","email":"abc2@email.com"},{"name":"abc1","email":"abc1@email.com"},{"name":"abc2"}]__

unset($responseAry[1]);

$responseAry = array_values($responseAry); //regenerate array(reindexing)

echo "------------removed 1--------";


echo json_encode($responseAry); //[{"name":"abc","email":"abc@email.com"},{"name":"abc2","email":"abc2@email.com"}]
```

**EDIT:**

As other option you can use `array_splice` method http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

```
$nesAry=array();
$nesAry["name"]="abc";
$nesAry["email"]="abc@email.com";

$nesAry1=array();
$nesAry1["name"]="abc1";
$nesAry1["email"]="abc1@email.com";

$nesAry2=array();
$nesAry2["name"]="abc2";
$nesAry2["email"]="abc2@email.com";


$responseAry = array();
$responseAry[0]=$nesAry;
$responseAry[1]=$nesAry1;
$responseAry[2]=$nesAry2;


echo json_encode($responseAry); // __here  output like this => [{"name":"abc","email":"abc2@email.com"},{"name":"abc1","email":"abc1@email.com"},{"name":"abc2"}]__

array_splice($responseAry,1,1);
echo "------------removed 1--------";


echo json_encode($responseAry);
```

Comment: is there any other option ?

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Your array when first converted to json is a so called "associative" array, and json_encode then exports it to the object you see in the first echo.

After your unset, the array is changed to a "numeric" array and json_encode will export the array with array keys.

Php it self does not care about how the array is used, but json_encode does.

You can use

`echo json_encode(array_values($responseAry));`

Or not change the final array you want to export