# Search and delete specific object inside an array in PHP

Tags: php

I have structure of an array like this :

```
[{"name":"username1","id":0},{"name":"username2","id":1}]
```

in my mysql database it is json encoded
i am trying to search for a specific id and delete that object and save other array as it is.

```
$arr_data=json_decode($jsonData);
         foreach(arr_data as $k=> $data)
            {
             if($request->id==$data->id)
                {
                  unset($arr_data[$k]);
                  $updateData =  DataTable::where(['id'=>$request->id])
                    ->update(['update_column' =>json_encode($arr_data)]);
                }
            }
```

Issue is my data is not stored in proper format after deleting.

New json formatted data is store in this format :

```
{"1":{"name":"username1","id":1}}
```

Any suggestion to solve this issue.

Comment: @LelioFaieta: In my above code index gets removed but i have to save remaining array element that format is not saved properly

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20373067/14481105 shows you how to remove keys from your new data.

Comment: [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-notes) keeps your array keys, unless it considers they can be omitted: "When encoding an array, if the keys are not a continuous numeric sequence starting from 0, all keys are encoded as strings, and specified explicitly for each key-value pair. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
$jsonData = '[{"name":"username1","id":0},{"name":"username2","id":1},{"name":"username2","id":2}]';

$arr_data=json_decode($jsonData);

if(($index = array_search($request->id, array_column( $arr_data, 'id'))) !== false) {
  unset($arr_data[$index]);
  $arr_data = array_values($arr_data);
}

$updateData =  DataTable::where(['id'=>$request->id])
                ->update(['update_column' =>json_encode($arr_data)]);
```