# How to get multiple tables and show them in JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have these tables in MySql

```
Countries -> countryId , countryName
Cities -> cityId , cityName , countryId
Neighborhoods -> neighborhoodId , neighborhoodName , cityId
```

The output should be like this

```
{
  "Countries": [
    {
      "countryId": "...",
      "countryName": "..."
    },
    {
      "countryId": "...",
      "countryName": "..."
    },
    {
      "countryId": "...",
      "countryName": "..."
    },
    {
      "countryId": "...",
      "countryName": "..."
    }
  ],
  "Cities": [
    {
      "cityId": "...",
      "cityName": "...",
      "countryId": "..."
    },
    {
      "cityId": "...",
      "cityName": "...",
      "countryId": "..."
    },
    {
      "cityId": "...",
      "cityName": "...",
      "countryId": "..."
    },
    {
      "cityId": "...",
      "cityName": "...",
      "countryId": "..."
    }
  ],
  "Neighborhoods": [
    {
      "neighborhoodId": "...",
      "neighborhoodName": "...",
      "cityId": "..."
    },
    {
      "neighborhoodId": "...",
      "neighborhoodName": "...",
      "cityId": "..."
    },
    {
      "neighborhoodId": "...",
      "neighborhoodName": "...",
      "cityId": "..."
    },
    {
      "neighborhoodId": "...",
      "neighborhoodName": "...",
      "cityId": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

**This code gives me data of one table only**

```
<?php
$connection = new mysqli('...', '...', '...', '...');

if ($connection->connect_errno)
{
    printf("Failed to connect to database");
    exit();
}

$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM Countries");
$dbdata = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $dbdata[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($dbdata);
?>
```

I'm new with PHP so I hope someone shows me how can I do it like above. Thank You....................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the code below, I added explaination as comments to the code itself.

```
<?php
    // connect your database   
    $conn = mysqli_connect('*****','('*****','('*****','('*****');
    
    // select the data from the 3 tables
    $country_res = mysqli_query($conn, 'select * from Countries');
    $city_res = mysqli_query($conn, 'select * from Cities');
    $nighbor_res = mysqli_query($conn, 'select * from Neighborhoods');

    // create 3 empty arrays to avoid notices, in case of 
    // empty results from database
    $countries = [];
    $cities = [];
    $neighborhoods = [];

    // fill countries array
    while($country = mysqli_fetch_assoc($country_res)) {
        $countries[] = $country;
    }
    // fill cities array
    while($city = mysqli_fetch_assoc($city_res)) {
        $cities[] = $city;
    }
    // fill neighborhoods array
    while($nighbor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nighbor_res)) {
        $neighborhoods[] = $nighbor;
    }

    // print your results in the format you mentioned 
    //(you have to use HTML code in order for the browser to
    // display it the way you need, so I used <pre> tag.)
    echo '<pre>';
    echo json_encode(['Countries' => $countries, 
                      'Cities' => $cities, 
                      'Neighborhoods' => $neighborhoods]);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this... for multiple tables run separate queries for every table.

```php
<?php
// DB connection
$con = mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***");
if(!$con){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
$Countries = mysqli_query($con," SELECT * from Countries");
$Cities = mysqli_query($con," SELECT * from Cities ");
$Neighborhoods = mysqli_query($con," SELECT postNumber,adCode from Neighborhoods ");

$Countries1 = array();
$Cities1 = array();
$Neighborhoods1 = array();

if($Countries && $Cities && $Neighborhoods){
        while($Countries11 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Countries)){
        $Countries1[] = $Countries11;
     }
     while($Neighborhoods11 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Neighborhoods)){
        $Neighborhoods1[] = $Neighborhoods11;
     }
     while($Cities11 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Cities)){
        $Cities1[] = $Cities11;
     }
}

$array = array();
$array["Countries1"] = $Countries1;
$array["Cities1"] = $Cities1;
$array["Neighborhoods1"] = $Neighborhoods1;

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Are you looking for something like that?

Comment: No, Check the JSON Update

Comment: I actually think it _is_ what you're looking for, just change "table1" to be "Countries", "table2" to be "Cities", and "table3" to be "Neighborhoods" in `$array` above and this answer should match your desired output.

Comment: @JesseQ The output is different from what I want, Check JSON above

Comment: @JesseQ The output https://ibb.co/nBnTXXd

Comment: @SE19 try now, updated

Comment: @SE19 OK, I think the difference is that you want to remove the keys? (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3...).  See if `array_values` gives you what you're after. You can see usage/output here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20373067/1732853

Comment: Tough break @DeveloperInside - you put in the work and didn't get the recognition. +1 from me!

Comment: @DeveloperInside  I gave the correct answer to the another answer because it's worked with me but your answer not working with me I don't know why, Anyway I gave you an upvote thanks for your time